# How to evaluate $-1/2 \choose 2$?

Tags: combinatorics

How to evaluate $-1/2 \choose 2$?  I came across this here:

[image]

But I don't see how they get the second line of the equation.

Comment: $\dbinom{n}{k} = \dfrac{n\left(n-1\right)\cdots\left(n-k+1\right)}{k!}$. This is how $\dbinom{n}{k}$ is defined.

Comment: @darij grinberg:  the definition I teach is that the binomial coefficient is the cardinality of $[n]^k$, and the formula is a theorem; but the definition assumes $n \geq k \geq 0$.

Comment: @CarlMummert that's true, but I'm pretty sure OP wants to extend it to non-integer $n$

Comment: @Dylan: I was just pointing out that the formula with factorials is not universally taken as a definition of the binomial coefficient. The key point in my mind is that there is indeed an extension of a function happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two different ways.

1) An analytic function has a unique Taylor series at the origin. By setting $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ and by computing $f(0),f'(0),f''(0)$ we get
$$ f(x) =  1 + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{3x^2}{8} + O(x^3).$$
Assuming that the identity
$$ (1-x)^n = \sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n}{k}(-x)^k $$
holds for non-natural values of $n$ too, we have $\binom{-1/2}{1}=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\binom{-1/2}{2}=\frac{3}{8}$.
In general, $\binom{-1/2}{k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}$.

2) This makes actually sense since
$$ \binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}$$
allows to extend the definition of $\binom{n}{k}$ in the $n=-\frac{1}{2}$ case, too:
$$ \binom{-1/2}{k} = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{k!\Gamma(1/2-k)}=(-1)^k \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}$$
and the binomial theorem is compatible with this extension.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2534659),
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{-1/2}{n}
&=\frac{\left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac32\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{2n-1}2\right)}{1\cdot2\cdots n}\\[6pt]
&=(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^nn!}\\[6pt]
&=(-1)^n\frac{\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}}{2^nn!}\\[9pt]
&=\left(-\frac14\right)^n\binom{2n}{n}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}=\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k!}.$$
So just put $\frac{1}{2}$ there.