# Checking if a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ is divergent or not

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients

The series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$ 
Is divergent.
Is this statement true?

I tried by Root Test.

Comment: The ratio test is simpler here.

Comment: Does the summand go to zero as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: $n\mapsto\binom{2n}{n}$ is quite blatantly an increasing and unbounded function. Maybe you mean $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2n)!}{4^n (n!)^2} = +\infty, $$ that is less trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this series is clearly divergent because each term it does not approach $0$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$. If we split up
$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$
like this:
$$\frac{n!\cdot(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(2n)}{n!n!}$$
$$\frac{\cdot(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(2n)}{n!}$$
$$\frac{n+1}{1}\cdot\frac{n+2}{2}\cdot...\cdot\frac{n+n}{n}$$
Then it becomes apparent that each term is always greater than one, and thus the sum obviously diverges.

Comment: Indeed the summands are $\binom{2n}{n}$, which we recognize as the maximum of all binomial coefficients choosing from $2n$.

Comment: @hardmath Yup. Definitely not divergent. :)

Comment: Yea True!! Thanks Bro.

Comment: @user458361 No problem, I'm glad to help.

If you found it helpful, don't forget to $\uparrow$ or $\checkmark$! :)

Answer (score 3):

The terms $\binom{2n}{n}= \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ in this summation are called [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) because in each row of Pascal's triangle, the middle entry is the largest.

Rather than approaching zero (as convergence of a series requires), these terms grow roughly like $4^n$.  A more precise estimate is given by the Wikipedia article (linked above) and proved to be an upper bound in this [previous MathOverflow Question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133732/upper-limit-on-the-central-binomial-coefficient):

$$ \binom{2n}{n} \approx \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} $$

Indeed [the related power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064216/generating-functions-and-central-binomial-coefficient) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} x^n$ converges to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$ for $x\in [-1/4,1/4)$.  One might suspect that the original form of the problem that inspired this Question was to determine the radius of convergence of this power series (which is $R=1/4$ by location of the nearest singularity to the origin).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots \cdot n\,\cdot\,(n+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot 2n}{1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots \cdot n\,\cdot\,1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots \cdot n}$$
After cancellatoin, the numerator consists of $n$ factors $\ge n$, the denominator of $n$ factors $\le n$. Hence the general summand is $\ge 1$, but miust tend to $0$ for convergence.