# Sum of Product of Central Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

The following constants have appeared in my research and I was wondering if they have a simpler expression. I have computed some values and I don't see any obvious combinatorial answer.

$$
c_n:= n! \sum_{i+j+k+l=n} \dbinom{2i}{i}\dbinom{2j}{j}\dbinom{2k}{k}\dbinom{2l}{l}
$$
Here $i,j,k,l$ are nonnegative integers. At the moment I don't think I need to know anything in particular about these constants, but it would be nice to know if they had a nice expression.

Comment: It's not a constant, it's a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Using generating functions, it's not hard to show that $c_n = 4^n  (n+1)!$.

Comment: Thanks! Looking back, there must have been an error in my program. I had written something which correctly computed the first three values of $c_n$ but $c_4$ for example had very large prime factors. I'm now getting your numbers, and I was able to show it with a generating function!

Answer (score 1):

Following Robert Israel's suggestion and using the generating function [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064216/generating-functions-and-central-binomial-coefficient): 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dbinom{2k}{k}x^k.
$$
We're looking for the $n^{th}$ coefficient of the fourth power of this generating function. So 
$$
\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} \right)^4 = \frac{1}{(1-4x)^2}.
$$
Recall that
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k
$$
so that when we differentiate
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)x^{k}
$$
and substitute in $4x$
$$
\frac{1}{(1-4x)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)4^k x^{k}.
$$
We see that the $n^{th}$ term is $(n+1)4^n$, so that when we multiply by $n!$ as in the definition of $c_n$ we get 
$$
c_n=4^n(n+1)!.
$$
Thanks again Robert!