# A certain sum of multinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, multinomial-coefficients

I would like to know if there is a nice expression for the sum
$$
 S(n)=\sum_{i+j=n}\binom{3i}{i,i,i}\binom{3j}{j,j,j}
$$
where $n$ is a non-negative integer. I have entered in the first few values of $S(n)$ to OEIS and gotten no results.

A similar looking sum which does have a nice expression is
$$
T(n)=\sum_{i+j=n}\binom{2i}{i}\binom{2j}{j}=4^n
$$
A reference for this is "New developments of an old identity"-Rui Duarte and Antonio Guedes de Oliveira (https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5424)

Comment: Could you detail what you point at exactly with $\binom{3i}{i,i,i}$ with an expression

Comment: @edx https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there is no closed form. Using Zeilberger's algorithm, you can show that the minimal recurrence relation with polynomial coefficients satisfied by $S(n)$ is
$$
27(3n+2)(3n+3)(3n+4)S(n)-3(2n+3)(9n^2+27n+22)S(n+1)+(n+2)^3S(n+2)=0
$$
Then, using Petkovšek's algorithm, you can show that this recurrence has no hypergeometric solutions. This means that $S(n)$ has no closed form involving only addition, multiplication, exponentiation with constant base, and the gamma function. I cannot rule out the possibility of a closed form involving expressions like $n^n$, but I have never seen something like that happen before with a summation of products of binomial coefficients.

Comment: While the answer is too advanced for me, your answer introduced me to research in " Zeilberger's algorithm". Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think this is a pretty convincing argument that there does not exist a nicer closed form.

Comment: I guess this also answers the question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352328/sum-of-product-of-two-multinomial-coefficients, which was a further generalization.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\on{S}}\pars{n} & \equiv \color{#44f}{\sum_{i\ +\ j\ =\ n}
{3i \choose i\ i\ i}{3j \choose j\ j\ j}} =
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}
{3i \choose i\ i\ i}{3j \choose j\ j\ j}\bracks{z^{n}}z^{i + j}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{3i \choose i\ i\ i}z^{i}}^{2} =
\bracks{z^{n}}\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{3i}! \over  i!^{3}}z^{i}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\bracks{\mbox{}_{2}\!\on{F}_{1}\pars{\left.\begin{array}{c}
\ds{1/3\quad 2/3}
\\
1
\end{array}\right\vert 27z}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & \underline{\ds{It\ doesn't\ seem\ very\ use\!ful\,!!!.}}
\end{align}