# Summation of special binomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}2 r \\ r\end{array}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{r}$

I have a feeling that this will be solved using some standard series but I cannot get around which series to use.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064216/generating-functions-and-central-binomial-coefficient).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$ \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}2 r \\ r\end{array}\right)x^{r}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 x}}$$