# Calculating $\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{u}{2}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi \sqrt{1-u}}{u-2}+\pi } }{u\sqrt{1-u}} \, du$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

What real tools would you employ for calculating the integral below? Some useful ideas I mean.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{u}{2}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi  \sqrt{1-u}}{u-2}+\pi } }{u\sqrt{1-u}} \, du$$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1+%28arctanh%28sqrt%281-%28u%2F2%29%29%29sqrt%7B%282+%5Cpi++sqrt%281-u%29%29%2F%28u-2%29%2B%5Cpi+%7D+%29%2F%28u+sqrt%281-u%29%29++du) gives an ugly result. And [finding a primitive is a no-go](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%28arctanh%28sqrt%281-%28u%2F2%29%29%29sqrt%7B%282+%5Cpi++sqrt%281-u%29%29%2F%28u-2%29%2B%5Cpi+%7D+%29%2F%28u+sqrt%281-u%29%29++du).

Comment: Does this integral... come from somewhere? Are you sure that there is a nice-ish closed form? (Usually on questions like this there is, but seeing WA's answer makes me a bit skeptical).

Comment: @theage I received is as a gift. I can't say more about the closed form until I have a way to make some progress on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Continuing from Leucippus' answer, through $\text{arctanh}(z)=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+z}{1-z}$, we just need to compute:

$$ I_1 = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{(1+t)\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\text{arcsinh}(1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log(1+\sqrt{2}),$$
$$ I_2 = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1+t^2})}{(1+t)\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt,\qquad I_3 = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1+t^2})}{(1+t)\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt$$
and since 
$$ \int\frac{dt}{(1+t)\sqrt{1+t^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\,\log\left(1-t+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+t^2}\right) $$
integration by parts looks like a good way to find $I_2$ and $I_3$ in terms of dilogarithms.

I have the strong feeling that the [Catalan-Harmonic identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148203/identity-with-harmonic-and-catalan-numbers) is involved, or some special value of the [Rogers L-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RogersL-Function.html).

---

If we substitute $t=\tan\theta$ in Leucippus' $(1)$ we get:
$$ I = 2\sqrt{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cos\theta}\right)\frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}$$
so we just need to compute:
$$ J_k = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{d\theta}{\cos^{2k+1}(\theta)(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)}=\int_{0}^{1}(1+t^2)^{k+1}\frac{dt}{1+t}$$
then exploit the Taylor series of $\text{arctanh}$.

Comment: I think $J_k$can be expressed in a beautiful form as I can see from the first few cases.

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist: I believe that too, but I will try harder tomorrow.

Comment: OK, no hurry with that (+1).

Comment: Good, using $\tan(x)\mapsto x$ is the key seems.

Comment: No need for further work, things are clear at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

For the integral
\begin{align}
I = \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{u}{2}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi  \sqrt{1-u}}{u-2}+\pi } }{u\sqrt{1-u}} \, du
\end{align}
let $t^{2} = 1-u$ to obtain the form
\begin{align}\tag{1}
I = 2 \sqrt{\pi} \, \int_{0}^{1} \tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 + t^{2}}{2}}\right) \, \frac{dt}{(1+t) \, \sqrt{1+t^{2}}}
\end{align}

---

**Method 1**: Jack D'Aurizio has provided one way to continue with equation (1)

---

**Method 2**: Another way to continue with equation (1) is to make the substitution $t = \sqrt{\cos \theta}$ to obtain
\begin{align}\tag{2}
I = \sqrt{2 \pi} \, \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\right) \, \frac{\sin\theta \, d\theta}{\sqrt{\cos\theta} \, (1 + \sqrt{\cos\theta})}
\end{align}
or, by letting $\theta = 4 \phi$, 
\begin{align}\tag{2.1}
I = 4 \, \sqrt{2 \pi} \, \int_{0}^{\pi/8} \frac{\ln(\cot\phi)) \, \sin(4\phi) \, d\phi}{\sqrt{\cos(4\phi)} \, (1 + \sqrt{\cos(4\phi)})}
\end{align}

Utilizing the series
\begin{align}\tag{3}
\ln(\cot\phi) = 2 \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(4k+2)\phi}{2k+1}
\end{align}
then the integral of (2.1) becomes
\begin{align}
I = 8 \sqrt{2 \pi} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k+1} \, \int_{0}^{\pi/8} \frac{ \cos(4k+2)\phi \, \sin(4\phi)}{\sqrt{\cos(4\phi)} \, (1 + \sqrt{\cos(4\phi)})} \, d\phi.
\end{align}
Now let $t = \cos(4 \phi)$ to obtain
\begin{align}\tag{4}
I &= 2 \, \sqrt{2\pi} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k+1} \, \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos\left(\left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right) \, \cos^{-1}(t)\right)}{\sqrt{t} \, (1 + \sqrt{t})} \, dt \\
&= 2 \, \sqrt{2\pi} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k+1} \, \int_{0}^{1} \frac{T_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(t)}{\sqrt{t} \, (1 + \sqrt{t})} \, dt
\end{align}
where $T_{n}(x)$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind. Making the substitution $t = x^{2}$ leads to
\begin{align}\tag{5}
I = 4 \, \sqrt{2\pi} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k+1} \, \int_{0}^{1} T_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(x^{2}) \, \frac{dx}{1 + x}
\end{align}

Let 
\begin{align}\tag{6}
J_{k} = \int_{0}^{1} T_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(x^{2}) \, \frac{dx}{1+x}
\end{align}
and use $T_{n+1}(x) = 2\, x \, T_{n}(x) - T_{n-1}(x)$ to obtain
\begin{align}
J_{k+1} &= 2 \, \int_{0}^{1} T_{k+1/2}(x^2) \, \frac{x^{2} \, dx}{1+x} - J_{k-1} \\
&= 2 \, \int_{0}^{1} \left[ (x+1) - 2 + \frac{1}{1+x} \right] \, T_{k+1/2}(x^2) \, dx - J_{k-1} \\
&= 2 \, \int_{0}^{1} x \, T_{k+1/2}(x^2) \, dx - 2 \, \int_{0}^{1} T_{k+1/2}(x^2) \, dx + 2 \, J_{k} - J_{k-1}. \tag{7}
\end{align}
It can be quickly determined that
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} x \, T_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(x^{2}) \, dx = \frac{1}{2((2k+1)^{2} - 4)} \, \left[ \sqrt{2} \, (2k+1) \, \left( \cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{k \pi}{2}\right) \right) - 4 \right] = \frac{P_{k}}{2((2k+1)^{2} - 4)}
\end{align}
and let 
\begin{align}
\sigma_{k} = \int_{0}^{1} T_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(x^2) \, dx
\end{align}
to take (7) into the form
\begin{align}\tag{8}
J_{k+1} - 2 \, J_{k} + J_{k-1} = \frac{P_{k}}{(2k+1)^{2} - 4} + \sigma_{k}.
\end{align}
By the same pattern the recurrence relation for $\sigma_{k}$ is seen to be
\begin{align}\tag{9}
\sigma_{k+1} + \sigma_{k-1} = \frac{P_{k}}{(2k+1)^{2} - 4}.
\end{align}
The first few values of $J_{k}$ and $\sigma_{k}$ are
\begin{align}\tag{10}
J_{0} &= \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \, \left( 1 + \sinh^{-1}(1) \right) \\
J_{1} &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \, \left( -8 + 7 \sqrt{2} + 3 (2 \sqrt{2} - 3) \, \sinh^{-1}(1) \right) - J_{0} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \, (-8 + 7 \sqrt{2}) + \frac{3 \sqrt{2} - 5}{\sqrt{2}} \, \sinh^{-1}(1) \\
\sigma_{0} &= \frac{1}{4} \, \left( 2 + \sqrt{2} \, \sinh^{-1}(1) \right) \\
\sigma_{1} &= \frac{1}{8} \, \left( 2 - 3 \sqrt{2} \, \sinh^{-1}(1) \right)
\end{align}
Condensing the results of equations (5-9) leads to
\begin{align}\tag{11}
I = 4 \sqrt{2 \pi} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{k}}{2k+1}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}\tag{12}
& J_{k+1} - 2 \, J_{k} + J_{k-1} = \frac{P_{k}}{(2k+1)^{2} - 4} + \sigma_{k} \\
& \sigma_{k+1} + \sigma_{k-1} = \frac{P_{k}}{(2k+1)^{2} - 4} \\
& P_{k} = \sqrt{2} \, (2k+1) \, \left(\cos\left(\frac{k \, \pi}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{k \, \pi}{2}\right) \right) - 4
\end{align}
and the first few values are obtained from (10). The general form of the desired integral can be expressed as
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{u}{2}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi  \sqrt{1-u}}{u-2}+\pi } }{u\sqrt{1-u}} \, du = A \, \sinh^{-1}(1) + B
\end{align}
where $A$ and $B$ can be determined from the above collected set of recurrence relations.

---

It can be seen that
\begin{align}
J_{k+2} - 2 \, J_{k+1} + 2 \, J_{k} - 2 \, J_{k-1} + J_{k-2} = \frac{P_{k+1}}{(2k+3)^{2} - 4} + \frac{P_{k}}{(2k+1)^{2} - 4} + \frac{P_{k-1}}{(2k-1)^{2} - 4}.
\end{align}
which makes the series (11) slightly easier to calculate term by term.

Comment: $(2.1)$ looks like a good point to plug in the [Fourier series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) of $\log\cot\phi$.

Comment: I feel you are really close to the final answer. Maybe $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{\cos((k+1/2)u)}{k+1/2}=\text{arctanh}(e^{-iu/2})+\text{arctanh}(e^{iu/2})$$ is the key?

Comment: Good job so far (+1)