# Evaluating $\sum^n_{x=1}{2x-1\choose x}t^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series, binomial-coefficients

> Is there any technique that I can use to evaluate 
>   $$\sum^n_{k=1}{2k-1\choose k}t^k, \quad \forall t\in\left(0,\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

It can be shown that the series converges even if $n\to \infty$ as
$$
\frac{{2k+1\choose k+1}t^{k+1}}{{2k-1\choose k}t^k}
 = 2t \times \frac{2k+1}{k+1}
 < 4t
 < 1.
$$
However, I can't find out how to simplify the summation.

Comment: @aryanbansal What's the value in the limit?

Comment: Oh i m sorry i read the question wrong really sorry

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237810/generating-function-for-binomial-coefficients-binom2nkn-with-fixed-k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k-1}kt^k=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}kt^k\underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow\frac1{\sqrt{1-4t}}$$

where the limit is well known as the generating function for the [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient). One can rewrite the partial sums using hypergeometric functions, but I doubt anything simpler can be done.