# Counting of Cardinal Trees (Trie) with Degree k and n Nodes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I've been diving into combinatorial problems related to cardinal trees and am trying to ascertain the count of such trees that have a degree *k* with *n* nodes. I stumbled upon some leads in "[Concrete Mathematics](https://ds.amu.edu.et/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/14168/Concrete%20Mathematics%20-%20640%20pages.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)", but couldn't find a definitive proof.

By a cardinal tree (or trie) of degree *k*, we mean a rooted tree in which each node has *k* positions for an edge to a child.

The answer is $C^k_n\equiv\binom{kn+1}{n}/(kn+1)$ according [to this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=1e9a91b3616e2ed3f17d8418533d7d74cbe9ff77), but I cannot figure out why, even dive into the text book I mentioned.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The full solution is hard, but we can quickly prove $C_n^k \le \binom{kn}{n-1}$ from the generalized Jacobson encoding mentioned on p. 282 (p. 8 of the PDF): it is a sequence of $kn$ bits, $n-1$ of which are `1`'s, and there are $\binom{kn}{n-1}$ ways to choose the positions of the `1`'s. (But there are further constraints, so this is only an upper bound.) Note that $\frac1{kn+1}\binom{kn+1}{n} = \frac1n \binom{kn}{n-1}$, so this upper bound overcounts exactly by a factor of $n$.

Comment: This has been asked several times on this site. See [vonbrand's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/835543/177399) for a proof via generating functions and Lagrange inversion. See [Brian's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1597743/177399) for an a great presentation of a bijective proof from _Concrete Mathematics_.

Comment: ... and see [Mike Earnest's new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4767385/383078) for a solution to *this* problem that follows the *Concrete Mathematics* approach.