# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{2n+1}(3n)!}{n!(2n+1)!4^{3n+1}}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to show that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{2n+1}(3n)!}{n!(2n+1)!4^{3n+1}}=1$$

I've tried binomially expanding different expressions to obtain this but I can't seem to find anything, though I don't really have much practice at this sort of thing. 
In particular, I am aware of the identities like 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!3^{2n}}=1,$$ 
but was unable to find anything suitable.

Comment: Where did you find this? I "proved" it with Wolfy's help, but two of the steps are magic. See my answer.

Comment: simplifize 
$\displaystyle \sum {_{3n}C_n}*\frac{3^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)*4^{3n+1}}$

Comment: This sum arises combinatorially from the generating function for the [Fuss-Catalan Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145768). The desired value can be obtatined by calculating $\frac{3}{4} C^{(3)}(\frac{9}{64})$, using the associated cubic equation provided in the linked answer.

Comment: This series is seen in problem 45 (ii) of [Advanced Problems in Mathematics](https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/handle/20.500.12657/31235/633792.pdf). It is a result from applying Lagrange inversion theorem to find a root of the equation $x-x^3/4=3/4$.

Answer (score 3):

Define $\, a_n := (3n)!/(n!(2n+1)!)\,$ which is [OEIS sequence A001764](http://oeis.org/A001764) and $\, b_n := a_n 3^{2n+1}/4^{3n+1}. \,$
The generating function
$$
 f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, x^n = \frac2{\sqrt{3x}}
 \sin\Big(\frac13\, \sin^{-1}\Big(\sqrt{27x/4}\Big)\Big) $$
and thus $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\, x^n = \frac34 f\Big(\frac9{64}x\Big) =
  \frac{4}{\sqrt{3x}} \sin\Big(\frac13\, \sin^{-1}
  \Big(\frac{9}{16}\sqrt{3x} \Big)\Big).  $$ 
Set $\, x = 1 \,$ and to prove
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \, =\,
  \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}} \sin\Big(\frac13 \sin^{-1}\Big(\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{16}\Big)\Big) = 1 $$
use the identity
 $\, \sin(3\theta) = 3 \sin(\theta)  - 4\sin(\theta)^3 \,$
where $\, \sin(\theta) = \sqrt{3}/4 \,$ to find
 $\, \sin(3\theta) = 9\sqrt{3}/16. $
In general, for $\, n>1 \,$ we get that $\, f(n^2/(n+1)^3) = (n+1)/n. \,$
Our example is $\, f(9/64) = 4/3.\,$

Comment: How do I see that $f$ is given by this function?

Comment: One is to look in OEIS which has the g.f. given. Another is to use a CAS such as Maple or Mathematica. There are other ways but they are harder and require much more  knowledge about enumberative combinatorics, for example. See the almost 100 references and links in the OEIS entry

Answer (score 0):

Let's group things a little.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{2n+1}(3n)!}{n!(2n+1)!4^{3n+1}}
=\dfrac34\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{2n}(3n)!}{n!(2n+1)!4^{3n}}
=\dfrac34\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (3^2/4^3)^n\frac{(3n)!}{n!(2n+1)!}
$
so let
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\frac{(3n)!}{n!(2n+1)!}
$.

This looks sort of
like a trisection of series,
but,
being lazy,
I threw it at Wolfy and,
to my great surprise,
 got
$f(x)
=\dfrac{2 \sin(\frac13 \sin^{-1}((3 \sqrt{3x}/2)))}{\sqrt{3x}}
$
which converges when
$|x| < 4/27$.

Putting $x=9/64$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(9/64)
&=\dfrac{2 \sin(\frac13 \sin^{-1}((3 \sqrt{3(9/64)}/2)))}{\sqrt{3(9/64)}}\\
&=\dfrac{2 \sin(\frac13 \sin^{-1}((3 \cdot 3\sqrt{3}/8/2)))}{3\sqrt{3}/8}\\
&=\dfrac{16 \sin(\frac13 \sin^{-1}(9\sqrt{3}/16))}{3\sqrt{3}}\\
&=\dfrac{16 (\sqrt{3}/4)}{3\sqrt{3}}
\qquad\text{again, according to Wolfy}\\
&=\dfrac43\\
\end{array}
$

Muptiplying by $\dfrac34$,
the result is $1$.

As to how I could
prove it by my self,
I don't know.

Comment: Amazing ! I directly gave a CAS $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{2n+1}(3n)!}{n!(2n+1)!4^{3n+1}}x^n$$ and received your answer.