# Generalizing a formula for enumerating rooted k-ary trees from doing so with ternary trees?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Recently I worked on a problem that involved finding the total possible rooted, labeled ternary trees with n vertices. After doing some math and using Lagrange inversion I found a formula for the total possible ternary trees with n vertices. I found great joy in exploring this problem as it took me on a small journey through a lot of combinatorial mathematics that I had not yet explored or experienced in school. I then posed the question, if we generalize the trees to be k-ary trees, is there some general formula?

Does such a formula exist? Im familiar with Cayley's formula, but this is slightly different since the trees in this case are rooted.

Can anyone explain to me the process of enumerating trees in such a way that you can generalize a formula for k-ary trees on n vertices? Where do you even start?

Comment: This perhaps ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145515/counting-k-ary-labelled-trees

Comment: @darijgrinberg close, but not quite. Those are for unlabelled trees. If our trees are labeled, the math gets more...involved.

Comment: To make the trees rooted, it seems like you just need a factor of $n$. Is the idea with $k$-ary trees that all vertices have degree $1$ or $k$?

Comment: Are your trees plane (i.e., does a vertex distinguish between its children)?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, each child of a given vertex are all distinct paths to a further subforest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combinatorial class of $k$-ary rooted unlabeled trees is

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} +
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SEQ}_{=k}(\mathcal{T})$$

Which gives the functional equation

$$T(z) = z + z \times T(z)^k$$

so that

$$z = \frac{T(z)}{1+T(z)^k}$$

We then have

$$n \times T_n = [z^{n-1}] T'(z)$$

and from the Cauchy Coefficient Formula

$$[z^{n-1}] T'(z) =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^n} T'(z) \; dz.$$

Now put $T(z) = w$ so that $T'(z) \; dz = dw$

and we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w^k)^n}{w^n} \; dw.$$

This is

$$T_n =
[[n\equiv 1 \bmod k]]
\frac{1}{n}
[w^{n-1}] (1+w^k)^n
\\ =
[[n\equiv 1 \bmod k]]
\frac{1}{n}
[w^{k\times (n-1)/k}] (1+w^k)^n
\\ =
[[n\equiv 1 \bmod k]]
\frac{1}{n}
[w^{(n-1)/k}] (1+w)^n.$$

We thus have for the answer

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
[[n\equiv 1 \bmod k]]
\frac{1}{n}
{n\choose (n-1)/k}.}$$

With this answer  we observe however that we can  get a better formula
by adhering to the convention that the  size of the tree is the number
of internal nodes  rather than the total number of  nodes. This yields
the class

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{E} +
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SEQ}_{=k}(\mathcal{T})$$

or
$$T(z) = 1 + z \times T(z)^k$$

so that

$$z = \frac{T(z)-1}{T(z)^k}$$

We get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{w^{kn}}{(w-1)^n} \; dw
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^n} \sum_{q=0}^{kn} {kn\choose q} (w-1)^q\; dw.$$

We thus have for the answer in terms of the number of internal nodes

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n}
{kn\choose n-1}.}$$

We then have for $k=3$ (ternary trees) the sequence

$$1, 3, 12, 55, 273, 1428, 7752, 43263, 246675, 1430715, \ldots$$

which points to [OEIS A001764](http://oeis.org/A001764), where we find
confirmation. Similarly, $k=4$ (quartic trees) gives

$$1, 4, 22, 140, 969, 7084, 53820, 420732, 3362260, 27343888, \ldots$$

which points to [OEIS A002293](http://oeis.org/A002293).

We may re-write the binomial coefficient as follows:

$$\frac{(kn)!}{n! \times ((k-1)n+1)!}$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{(k-1)n+1}
{kn\choose n}.}$$

This form  is sometimes  preferred because it  is defined  when $n=0$,
where it  yields the value  one (one empty  tree). It also  happens to
match the standard Catalan number formula when $k=2.$

**Addendum.**  I did not  read the question properly  and answered
for  rooted ordered  unlabeled  k-ary plane  trees  instead of  rooted
labeled k-ary trees. The combinatorial class now becomes

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} +
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}_{=k}(\mathcal{T})$$

or

$$T(z) = z + z \times \frac{1}{k!} T(z)^k$$

so that

$$z = \frac{T(z)}{1+T(z)^k/k!}.$$

The computation is the same as before and we obtain
(multiply by $n!$ for an EGF)

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
[[n\equiv 1 \bmod k]]
\frac{(n-1)!}{k!^{(n-1)/k}}
{n\choose (n-1)/k}.}$$

We get for binary trees on $n=2m+1$ nodes

$$1, 3, 60, 3150, 317520, 52390800, 12843230400, 4382752374000,
\\ 1986847742880000, 1155153277710432000, 838011196011749760000,
\ldots $$

which is [OEIS A036770](http://oeis.org/A036770). For ternary trees on
$n=3m+1$ nodes we find

$$1, 4, 420, 201600, 264264000, 734557824000, 3723191087616000,
\\ 31125877492469760000, 399532678960326912000000, \ldots $$

which  is [OEIS  A036771](http://oeis.org/A036771).  Quartic trees  on
$n=4m+1$ nodes then yield

$$1, 5, 2520, 9909900, 150089940000, 6217438242015000,
\\ 574985352122181000000, 103753754577643425255000000, \ldots$$

which is [OEIS A036772](http://oeis.org/A036772).

For convenience we may write $n=mk+1$ to do without the Iverson
bracket and get

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{(mk)!}{k!^m}
{mk+1\choose m}.}$$

**Concluding  remark.**  The  permutation  group  acting  on  the
children  may sensibly  be  taken  to be  the  one  consisting of  the
identity permutation, the cyclic group  or the symmetric group.  These
correspond  to   the  operators  $\textsc{SEQ},$   $\textsc{CYC}$  and
$\textsc{SET}.$  The cyclic  case  signifies that  the  tree is  being
embedded in three-space and rooted at the origin so that we may rotate
the children. Children at a given depth are all in the same horizontal
plane parallel to  the plane at $z=0$ and children  of the same parent
are located on a circle in their  plane separated by an angle of $2\pi
/k$ radians.

A  recent comment  by OP  indicates  what is  being asked  for is  the
operator $\textsc{SEQ}$ (plane trees).  We get in the labeled case

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
[[n\equiv 1 \bmod k]]
(n-1)! {n\choose (n-1)/k}.}$$

These are not in the OEIS. I  suspect this is because the labeled case
is obtained from the unlabeled  case by trivially distributing the $n$
labels in $n!$ ways into the  nodes of an unlabeled source tree.  What
happens  here  is  that  the   $\textsc{SEQ}$  operator  is  the  same
algebraically in  the labeled and  the unlabeled case, which  does not
hold  for $\textsc{CYC}$  and  $\textsc{SET}.$  The sequence  operator
admits  no symmetries,  which is  why  all $n!$  distributions of  the
labels are different, forming an orbit of order one.

Comment: This is an awesome explanation. Sorry for the confusion on the unlabeled property. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Thank you, I hope you find it useful.